# how to loop through certain directories in a directory structure in python?

Tags: python, file, loops, operating-system

I have the following directory structure

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the pics, there are a lot of .0 files in different directories. This directory structure exists for 36 folders(Human_C1 to C36) and each Human_C[num] folder has a 1_image_contours folder which has a contours folder with all related .0 files.

These .0 files contain some co-ordinates(x,y). I wish to loop through all these files, take the data in them and put it in an excel sheet(I am using pandas for this).

The problem is, how I loop through only these set of files and none else? (there can be .0 files in contour_image folders also)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since your structure is not recursive I would recommend this:

```
import glob
zero_files_list = glob.glob("spinux/generated/Human_C*/*/contours/*.0")
for f in zero_files_list:
    print("do something with "+f)
```

Run it from the parent directory of `spinux` or you'll have no match!

It will expand the pattern for the fixed directory tree above, just as if you used `ls` or `echo` in a linux shell.